# Event based on Windows file locked error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, filelock

I am trying to work out how I can create a dotnet event that fires when somebody tries to access a file shared on my computer that is locked (as shown in compmgmt.msc).

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Which part? The event log entry? Or listening for the event itself?

Comment: I want to create an event that executes some code when somebody tries to open a shared file that is locked.

Comment: Bump, anybody know how I can achieve this?